# Cognitive Services: Face Identification

Tags: face-detection, azure-cognitive-services

is it possible to add new persons to group afterwards, without re-submitting and re-training everything every time a new person is added?

The sample application (https://github.com/Microsoft/Cognitive-Face-Python) requires images per person in separate directories, to be submitted as a group.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add persons to a group anytime you want as long as you don't exceed the limits. However in order for the new persons (or the faces you added for the existing persons) to be used in the "Identify" process you need to call "train". Otherwise newly added persons (or faces) won't be found.

Comment: It is also mentioned in documentation everywhere, that the group needs to be trained. However, in their Intelligent Kiosk example, I cannot find any training step but it still works? (It might be there, just not commented very well or being too obvious.)  https://github.com/Microsoft/Cognitive-Samples-IntelligentKiosk

Comment: I think that's because that example uses FaceList rather then PersonGroup option. FaceList do not require training (except for LargeFaceList).